# having trouble redirecting bean from servlet to jsf .xhtml page

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

I'm attempting to redirect a bean from a servlet to a jsf page. This is a school project and I had asked my professor for help and he provided the following code as a solution. I saw it running perfectly in my project but on his machine because I had gone to his office for help. Now that I'm home I added the same four lines of code to my project but its not redirecting to the .xhtml page.

debugging shows that its failing at the ExternalContext line. Also, when catching the exception the stack trace just says "null". I don't get why my project, exact same code that i saw work on my professors computer, isn't working. lol.

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("bean", myBean);
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext(); //failing here
externalContext.redirect("myJSPPage.xhtml");
```

Answer (score 0):

`FacesContext` can only exists if `FacesServlet` is controlling the current request, otherwise `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` will return `null`.  This code will work if it's executed in a method inside a JSF managed bean. So, maybe you just copiedthis code and pasted it in your custom servlet.

Comment: Hmmm thanks. I saw it working correctly though. Is there something I need to set in my web.xml file or persistence unit maybe? I had my professor email the revised and working code from his machine but when i tried running it on my machine, same problem. I did check my xml files and everything is the same. Idk